# Can additional object properties in coffeescript/javascript be added dynamically to an existing object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

Can additional object properties in coffeescript/javascript be added dynamically to an existing object?

For example:

`var fred = { name: "Fred", species: "Sub-Human" };`

Now later, for example, I want to add college major to get this:

`{ name: "Fred", species: "Sub-Human", major: "Computer Science" }`

And... how does this affect, or does it affect performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes;

```
fred["major"] = "Computer Science";
```

All properties on an object can be accessed by using square brackets and the property name. This method also allows you to set new properties.

```
fred.major = "Computer Science";
```

This will also work fine.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, JavaScript objects are completely dynamic.

You can use dot notation with a property name literal:

```
fred.major = "Computer Science";
```

or brackets notation with a property name string:

```
fred["major"] = "Computer Science";
```

Literals can be optimized more by the JavaScript engine, strings can be the result of any expression (so, `fred["m" + "ajo" + "r"] = ...` would work) and can include characters (like spaces — yes, really —) that you can't use in a property name literal.

I suggest working through some basic JavaScript tutorials (if you want to learn JavaScript) or CoffeeScript tutorials (if you want to learn CoffeeScript).

Comment: Really,... It's exact the answer I gave.

Comment: @Mouser: It wasn't as of when I started writing my answer. The answer that was there when I started was misleading, suggesting that you had to use a string. I thought something more complete was appropriate.

Comment: True give you that ;-) Cuddos for giving the correct answer. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I knew you can do <code>delete fred.major</code> Thought there might be something like <code>add fred.gender = "Male"</code> or something similar, but now I really am understanding what "weakly-typed" means. I come from a Java background, so none of this would fly due to scope, etc... New to JS,so thanks. :) Hopefully people won't kill me over asking a simple question.

Comment: @JoshuaMichael: Ah, yes, I see that logic. BTW, side note about `delete`: On modern engines, if you use `delete` to remove a property, subsequent property lookups on that object may be slower (although with modern engines it rarely matters). This is because using `delete` frequently causes the JavaScript engine to stop using an optimized object and fall back on a simple map or dictionary object. *Adding* properties doesn't do that, but `delete` can.

Comment: @T.J Crowder: Good to know.